# Bridge DependencyProperty from two binding sources

Tags: c#, wpf

Consider this scenario, using MVVM:

On my ModelView, I have one property, of type "string", it does notify the change of properties through INotifyPropertyChanged.

In the view, there is (or not) one control, with a DependencyProperty "Notification" of a type which is not a string. That control may or may not change that property depending on facts that only the control knows (neither the ModelView or the View knows about those). That control might even be on other View which may or may not be on the current visual tree.

In the View, I need a bridge between that control's DependencyProperty and the ViewModel's property, so that changing the view property makes the control change its property, and changing the control's DependencyProperty makes the viewmodel's property change its value.

I've got it to work, but I don't think it's an elegant solution. I might be thinking fuzzy these days so I'm asking if there's something obvious that I might have missed.

The obvious way would be either having the ViewModel Property be a DependencyProperty (so it could be bound two ways), however that is not possible right now (plus, it'd break the MVVM pattern, adding view-specific implementations to the viewmodel).

The other obvious way would be binding the Control's DependencyProperty to the ViewModel's property: this works, but just for one view... several properties cannot (or, I don't know how to do it) be bound to the same DependencyProperty: when I set one binding, I lose the other.

Currently this is what I do:

```cs
public class BaseViewUserControl : UserControl
{
    // Dependency property, bound to the view's property
    public string AudioNotification
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(AudioNotificationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AudioNotificationProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AudioNotificationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AudioNotification", typeof(string), typeof(BaseViewUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("None", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnAudioNotificationPropertyChanged));

    // Dependency property, bound to the control's dependency property
    public AudioNotificationType AudioNotificationToControl
    {
        get { return (AudioNotificationType)GetValue(AudioNotificationToControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AudioNotificationToControlProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AudioNotificationToControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AudioNotificationToControl", typeof(AudioNotificationType), typeof(BaseViewUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(AudioNotificationType.None, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, null, OnAudioNotificationToControlCoerceValue));

    // Converter
    private static IValueConverter _audioNotificationTypeConverter;
    private static IValueConverter AudioNotificationTypeConverter
    {
        get { return _audioNotificationTypeConverter ?? (_audioNotificationTypeConverter = new AudioNotificationConverter()); }
    }
    
    private Binding _audioNotificationBinding;
    private bool PrepareAudioNotificationControlBinding()
    {
        if (_audioNotificationBinding != null) return true;
        var b = this.FindVisualTreeRoot().TryFindChild<AudioNotification>();
        if (b == null) return false;
        _audioNotificationBinding = new Binding { Source = b, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Path = new PropertyPath("Notification") };
        SetBinding(AudioNotificationToControlProperty, _audioNotificationBinding);
        return true;
    }
    private static void OnAudioNotificationPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(source is BaseViewUserControl)) return;

        var src = (BaseViewUserControl)source;
        if(src.PrepareAudioNotificationControlBinding())
        {
            var val = AudioNotificationTypeConverter.ConvertValue<AudioNotificationType>(e.NewValue);
            src.AudioNotificationToControl = val;
        }
    }
    
    private static object OnAudioNotificationToControlCoerceValue(DependencyObject source, object basevalue)
    {
        if (!(source is BaseViewUserControl)) return basevalue;
        var src = (BaseViewUserControl)source;
        var val = AudioNotificationTypeConverter.ConvertBackValue<string>(basevalue);
        src.AudioNotification = val;
        return basevalue;
    }

    public BaseViewUserControl()
    {
        var ab = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("AudibleNotification"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        SetBinding(AudibleNotificationProperty, ab);
    }
}
```

***NOTE:*** *I'm using this for several things, not just for audio notification (that's an example only). Do not rely on the names to give a solution (if any), this needs to be quite generic. Also, any typos come from simplifying the code to the problem (I've removed much code and changed some property names for clarification).*

As I said, it works... I just find it quite not-elegant and I'm sure there should be a better solution than this.

Any suggestions will be more than welcome.

---

## Update

Based on Julien's code, I made this Behavior, which does exactly what I wanted. I implemented it using `Converter`, but for clarity's sake, I ended up doing the conversion on the control itself and using `strings` to pass variables along *(with an undocumented property in the control's if I still want to use the native data type)*

```cs
public class BridgePropertyBinderBehavior : Behavior<DependencyObject>
{
  public static BridgePropertyBinderBehavior PrepareBindingToControl(FrameworkElement sourceView, string viewModelPropertyPath, FrameworkElement targetControl, string controlPropertyPath)
  {
    var b = new BridgePropertyBinderBehavior();
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(b, AProperty, new Binding(viewModelPropertyPath) { Source = sourceView.DataContext, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, BindsDirectlyToSource = true, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(b, BProperty, new Binding(controlPropertyPath) { Source = targetControl, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
    Interaction.GetBehaviors(sourceView).Add(b);
    return b;
  }

  public object A { get { return GetValue(AProperty); } set { SetValue(AProperty, value); } }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(object), typeof(BridgePropertyBinderBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => ((BridgePropertyBinderBehavior)d).OnAChanged(e.NewValue)));

  public object B { get { return GetValue(BProperty); } set { SetValue(BProperty, value); } }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(object), typeof(BridgePropertyBinderBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => ((BridgePropertyBinderBehavior)d).OnBChanged(e.NewValue)));

  private void OnAChanged(object value) { B = value; }
  private void OnBChanged(object value) { A = value; }

  protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
  {
    return new BridgePropertyBinderBehavior();
  }
}
```

Which I use like this on my view:

```cs
var audioNotificationControl = this.FindVisualTreeRoot().TryFindChild<AudioNotification>();
BridgePropertyBinderBehavior.PrepareBindingToControl(this, "AudioNotification", audioNotificationControl, "Notification");
```

or

```xml
<AudioNotification x:Name="Control">
  <ia:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <BridgePropertyBinderBehavior
      A="{Binding Path=Notification, ElementName=Control, Mode=TwoWay}"
      B="{Binding Path=AudioNotification, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </ia:Interaction.Behaviors>
</AudioNotification>
```

I've accepted his answer since it's what got me on the right track, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to bind one DP to two sources, one as a source and the other as a target. I actually have a behavior to do that.

The principle of this behavior is quite simple: it uses two dependency properties and makes the data of one (`In`) flows into the other (`Out`). Bind `In` with a one way binding and `Out` with a one way to source binding and you're done.

```
public class BindingBehavior : Behavior<DependencyObject> {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "In",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(BindingBehavior),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => ((BindingBehavior) d).OnInPropertyChanged(e.NewValue)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Out",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(BindingBehavior),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    // Bind OneWay
    public object In {
        get { return GetValue(InProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InProperty, value); }
    }

    // Bind OneWayToSource
    public object Out {
        get { return GetValue(OutProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutProperty, value); }
    }

    private void OnInPropertyChanged(object value) {
        Out = value;
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() {
        return new BindingBehavior();
    }

}
```

This behavior needs a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity from Blend SDK, which you might be familiar with.

Assuming you remove your `string` property and only keep a `AudioNotificationType` one named `AudtioNotification`, the usage should be similar to:

```
<YourView x:Name="View">
  <YourControl x:Name="Control" AudioNotification="{Binding Notification, ElementName=View}>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <BindingBehavior
        In="{Binding AudioNotification, ElementName=Control, Mode=OneWay}"
        Out="{Binding YourVmProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource, Converter=YourConverter}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </YourControl>
</YourView>
```

You can place the behavior on any element being on the correct name scope for resolving element names and having the view model as the data context.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this only does one way binding between "In" and "Out" (with a DP in-between). The problem here is that "Out" would never be updated, even if "In" changed, would it? I'd need "In" updated when "Out" changed, and "Out" updated when "In" changed (which is what I'm doing on my code).

Comment: `Out` is updated when `In` is changed (see `OnInPropertyChanged`). You could easily modify the behavior to change `In` when `Out` is changed.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant the opposite (`In` not updated when `Out` changed). I could of course add a `OnPropertyChangedCallback` handler to update `In`, but then that'd remove the binding once I set the property value (which happens when it's OneWay). Solution to that would be binding two-ways and modify the property on the coerce callback... but then that's exactly what I am doing on my code. I'll try your behaviour later anyway and see if I have the concepts wrong in my head (which is entirely possible since I'm quite new to WPF).

Comment: Accepted as answer since it got me on track to a very clear way of solving the problem

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it *might* be a useful time to add a layer of abstraction. I know. Ick. But bear with me.

What if you had a bridge object that an abitrary number of things can bind to that handles the notifications on change. It doesn't even need to be that complex. Just something that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and then has a property (or properties) that release a notification on change. That way, your ViewModel, your View and your control can all bind to the same property on this bridge object and when one of those changes the bridge object's property, all the others will know that it's time to change as well. As long as all the objects are bound two-way, everything should synch just fine.

That's essentially what you've done on your BaseViewUserControl, but encapsulating the behavior in a separate object might provide you flexibility benefits.

Comment: Agreed, I will surely add a new layer for this. I was just trying to make sure this was the way to go before adding that layer. Seems it is. WPF looks so half-baked with things like this!